# react 16 fragment functional component and typescript TS2605

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm using tsx with React. My firsts days with React and not too much knowledge about Typescript.

---

@types/react 16.0.25

react 16.1.1

---

In my tsconfig.json I have  "noImplicitAny": false

When I write a functional component that returns a fragment:

```
function MyComponent() {
    return [<div>1</div>, <div>2</div>];
}
```

Typescript complains:

```
    TS2605: JSX element type 'Element[]' is not a constructor function for JSX elements.
  Property 'render' is missing in type 'Element[]'.
```

If I define the type :any I skip the error

```
function MyComponent():any {
    return [<div>1</div>, <div>2</div>];
}
```

Is this an issue from @types/react or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I'm pretty sure its a @types/react issue. It seems like that had the same problem back then here: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/20356. Generally it 's recommended to use [Fragments](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html) when returning an array of elements